# Add multiple field search in SearchView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, searchview

I have `SearchView` and I can search in `RecyclerView` with this code:

```
private List<Question> filter(List<Question> models, String query) {
        query = query.toLowerCase();

        final List<Question> filteredModelList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Question model : models) {
            final String text = model.getTitle().toLowerCase();
            if (text.contains(query)) {
                filteredModelList.add(model);
            }
        }
        return filteredModelList;
    }
```

As you can see this code only search on `model.getTitle()`, so, is there any way to search in 2 filed `model.getTitle()` and `model.getContent()`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below code,

```
private List<Question> filter(List<Question> models, String query) {
    query = query.toLowerCase();
    final List<Question> filteredModelList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Question model : models) {
        final String textTitle = model.getTitle().toLowerCase();
        final String textContent = model.getTitle().toLowerCase();
        if (textTitle.contains(query) || textContent.contains(query)) {
            filteredModelList.add(model);
        }
    }
    return filteredModelList;
}
```